# Retrieving multiple <td> in a table

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> Info! </td>
<td> Null </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
Info 2
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var elem = $("tr");
```

I've tried:

```
elem.find("td").get(0);
```

And

```
elem[1].find("td").get(0);
```

It works fine for selecting the different table rows, but I can't select the `<td>`.

But that only gets me the first row's `<td>` tag.

How would I get the 2nd tr's td tag?

Comment: Do you want the first `<td>` in every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `elem` contains all the `<tr>` elements, then:

```
elem.eq(1).find('td');
```

`1`, because JavaScript is zero-indexed (so the first is `0`, the second is `1`, etc).

Or, slightly more cumbersome:

```
elem.filter(':nth-child(2)').find('td');
```

`2` because CSS's `:nth-child()` pseudo-class is one-based (so the first is `1`, the second is `2`).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- jQuery:

  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 1):

Among other solutions, you can use the `nth-of-type` selector:

```
$('tr td:nth-of-type(2)')
```

So to expand on your trials:

```
var elem = $("tr");

elem.find('td:nth-of-type(2)');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2) td')
```

Any of these should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css selector:

```
$("tr:nth-child(2) td")
```

or the jquery [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) selector (*`0` index based*):

```
$("tr:eq(1) td")
```